# Rails 4 - Yaml configuration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this file `config/application.yml`

```
settings:
  info:
    name: MyAppName
    domain: example.com
  contact:
    email: mail@example.com
    phone: 1234567890
```

And in the `environment.rb` i have this

```
AppConfig = YAML::load_file('config/application.yml')
```

So now i can access this by using `AppConfig["settings"]["info"]["name"]`

How can i access this by using `AppConfig.settings.info.name` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Rails 4.2 or higher, you can use `config_for` for the config files. They need to be placed under /config folder. (haven't tried otherwise)

In your case it would be: `config = Rails.application.config_for(:application)`

This is more clear and Rails way to load configs into application.

Then you can use OpenStruct to have dot notation enabled for it.

`APP_CONFIG = OpenStruct.new(config)`

Answer (score 6):

Here's an easy way to do this without any gems, though I'm not sure about the performance if you are doing this frequently.

The idea is to first convert the data to JSON, and then parse the JSON to OpenStruct (which is built into Ruby):

```
json_data = YAML::load_file('config/application.yml').to_json
data = JSON.parse(json_data, object_class: OpenStruct)
```

This will deeply convert all hashes to OpenStructs and also correctly handles arrays.

As an example, if I have this YAML:

```
people:
  -
    name: 'Jerry Rasmussen'
    address:
      address_1: '123 Street St'
  -
    name: 'Sara DeWetzel'
```

Then it can be loaded and used like so:

```
json_data = YAML::load_file('config/people.yml').to_json
data = JSON.parse(json_data, object_class: OpenStruct)

data.people.first.name
 => Jerry Rasmussen
data.people.first.address.address_1
 => 123 Street St
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to convert a Hash into a construct that's accessible via dot syntax. You can either use a gem like [settingslogic gem](https://github.com/settingslogic/settingslogic) and point it to your `application.yml` file OR take a look at the source to find out the process by which this is done. I think the easiest and most robust approach is to use a popular (read: well tested in the wild) and well-documented gem vs. rolling your own.

```
# app/models/settings.rb
class Settings < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/application.yml"
  namespace Rails.env
end
```

You can then access the individual settings via

```
Settings.info.name
# MyAppName
```

Comment: This is the way that Gitlab does it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [recursive-open-struct gem](https://github.com/aetherknight/recursive-open-struct)

```
app_config = YAML.load_file('config/application.yml').with_indifferent_access
ros = RecursiveOpenStruct.new(app_config)

puts ros.settings.info.name # MyAppName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install [hash dot gem](https://github.com/adsteel/hash_dot)

And, then use following code.

```
require 'hash_dot'
AppConfig = YAML::load_file('config/application.yml')
```

and, now call

```
AppConfig.settings.info.name
```

It will return your desired out put.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into rails native

> [ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions < Hash](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/OrderedOptions.html)

You still would have to convert your hashes with some function though, but as a starting point, if you really don't want any gem.